# export $(dbus-launch) does not work via application or script

Tags: shell-script, d-bus, yocto

I'm working on an embedded linux board running yocto custom distribution (https://github.com/phytec/meta-ampliphy) based on poky. I have 2 C apps running simultaneously and intercom'ing via dbus. During every reboot I need to mandatorily run (root account)

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

in the board's terminal for apps to work.
I tried 2 scenarios which do not work:

1. wrote below two lines in the C code in the main function before initializing anything

```
    strcpy(bash_cmd, "export $(dbus-launch)");
    system(bash_cmd);
```

2. wrote a shell script and calling it automatically during bootup (or manually running) which just contains below 2 lines. Not working though.

```
    #!/bin/bash  
    export $(dbus-launch)
```

Someone suggested `"eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)"` to include in shell script which did not work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: If it is easier for you, start your 2 apps with `dbus-run-session bash -c 'app1 & app2'` then you get a session daemon that lives until the 2 apps exit.

Comment: You need to »run« a commented `#export`?! Even if not commented, an `export` is worth nothing for commands issued in an independent shell.

Comment: @meuh- this is working but can this be a long term solution? I mean can I use this for production environment?

Comment: @Philippos - i meant root actually with #. That's just a copy paste error. Original script doesn't have that. Thanks for mentioning that export means nothing but can you also suggest a solution?

Comment: How are your apps started? Can you change that to `export $(dbus-launch) && /bin/myApp`?

Comment: We are still in development stage so I'm starting the apps manually now from terminal. I tried your solution, it is working but when I run 'ps' command apps still exist as Z in STAT. They are not getting killed permanently even with "kill -9 pid". They are not running ofcourse but they are just there as many times I run the script.  ```348 root      2496 T    {export_dbus.sh} /bin/bash ./export_dbus.sh
354 root         0 Z    [main-code]  383 root      2496 T    {export_dbus.sh} /bin/bash ./export_dbus.sh
  389 root         0 Z    [main-code]```